# Optimal solution for the Iowa Gambling Task?

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

The Iowa Gambling Task is used to demonstrate our intuition with statistics and probability.

Essentially the subject sits in front of four decks. Each round, the participant can draw from any deck of her choosing. Each deck produces "wins" or "losses" along different probabilities. (Maybe the wins/losses vary in magnitudes, but let's simplify to the binary win/loss here). The goal is to maximize your wins (presumably by sampling from each deck to identify the deck with the best odds, then draw exclusively from that deck).

It's described more fully here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iowa_gambling_task

One of the interesting things about this task is that most people fall into a pretty good intuitive strategy, even if they couldn't formalize what they're doing.

Just how hard is it to formalize an optimal approach here? Has anyone rigorously tackled this? (The research on the problem I can find so far is about childhood development and psychology, not mathematics, maybe it's been covered, I'm not sure.)

It's an interesting problem because seems to involve a few areas of mathematics, optimal stopping theory (for how long to sample):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_stopping

And maybe something about statistical confidence. If you've drawn from one deck three times and it pays out 2/3, that should impact your decisions differently than if you had drawn from a deck 300 times and seeing it pay out 2/3.

Any ideas on ways to tackle this more rigorously?

Comment: We might have to specify either a cost for each draw, or a maximum number of rounds for this question to be sensible, I'm not sure. Even if you had an infinite number of draws that only hurt you by opportunity cost, though, the probabilities of each deck might diverge enough that extra confidence in a 1/10 payout deck might never be worth it if your current deck continues to payout above 50%. So maybe those constraints aren't required. Then again, infinity does weird things to optimal gambling strategy (See: St. Petersburg Paradox http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox ).

Comment: Tackling "how much value do we get from each flip," it might be useful to formalize as:

Suppose we have only two decks. One pays out with p = 0.5. The other one pays out somewhere between 0 and 1 exclusive, we'll call that p1. You want a strategy that allows you to identify which deck has the higher payout with x% confidence in as few moves as possible, where (1-x) < |(.5 - p1)|... so if the gap is narrower, you need more certainty. If p1 = .5001, you'd better be really sure it's not .4999. If p1 = .999, you can be off a bit and it won't matter.

Comment: Maybe limit further, p1 can only be .25 or .75. If you flip four times, what are the odds that you are "misled?" We'll define "misled" as receiving 3 or 4 wins when p1 = .25, or receiving 0 or 1 wins while p1 = .75. Of sixteen possible results for each p1 value, five are misleading. TODO: calc odds of a misleading result, and then use that to determine confidence, and then calc odds for a misleading result with greater / fewer flips, to see how it changes over time.

Oh, I say "flips" or "draws," those should be considered synonymous (even though technically in a finite deck they wouldn't be.)